# Django, how to sum queryset value in dictionary values

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-models, django-views

I have the following queryset dictionary:

```
{'Key_1': [100.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'Key_2': [103.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

In which I have as Key the category of my products and as items 12 values, that represent the sum of each month.
I want to calculate the cross sum of all keys of each items, as the following example:

```
{'Total': [203.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

How could I obtain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip`, `sum`, and list comprehension:

```
d = {
    'Key_1': [100.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    'Key_2': [103.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
}

sum_dict = {
    'Total': [sum(t) for t in zip(*d.values())],
}
# sum_dict = {'Total': [203.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

Step-by-step explanation of `[sum(t) for t in zip(*d.values())]`:

1. `[sum(t) for t in zip([100.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [103.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]`
2. `[sum(t) for t in [(100.0, 103.0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]]`
3. `[sum((100.0, 103.0)), sum((0, 0)), sum((0, 0)), sum((0, 0)), sum((0, 0)), sum((0, 0)), sum((0, 0)), sum((0, 0)), sum((0, 0)), sum((0, 0)), sum((0, 0)), sum((0, 0))]`
4. `[203.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`